# How to represent one decimal number separated by C

Tags: c, decimal, division

I want to divide `152799920` expressed in decimal numbers into `152/799/920` expressions and store them separately in `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`, respectively.
In other words, when I output values ​​for `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` later, `p1 = 152`, `p2 = 799`, and `p3 = 920` are the result.

How do I implement the above method in C code?

Comment: A combination of the `/` and `%` operators. Google it, it's a common beginner's exercise.

Comment: `p3 = 152799920 % 1000` , `p2 = 152799920/1000 % 1000` , `p1 = 152799920/(1000*1000) % 1000`

Comment: If the number was `-152799920`, what would you expect for `p1,p2,p3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your problem,** simply use the integer division `/` and modulus `%` operator to get your desired digits. In this case, it would be

```
int main()
{
    int n = 152799920;
    int p1 = n / 1000000; // Extract most significant three digits
    int p2 = (n % 1000000)/1000; // Extract middle three digits
    int p3 = n % 1000; // Extract least significant three digits
    printf("%d/%d/%d", p1, p2, p3);

    return 0;
}
```

**But what about extracting any range of digits?** Suppose that you index your decimal digits. The smallest rightmost digit is referred as digit 0, whereas the largest (in this case) would be 8. Note that the index of the digits correspond to the base-10 scientific notation, meaning that digit 8 refers to the 10^8 place value.

To extract a range of digits of an int from `LSD` to `MSD` in int form, the solution will be of this form (note you have to manually replace `[MSD]`, `[LSD]` them with numbers in the actual code):

```
int p = (n % (int) 1E[MSD + 1])/LSD
```

If you want to extract the digits more significant than a given `LSD`, it reduces to `int p = n / LSD`.

Hence, your solution can also be expressed as here below using scientific E-notation. Please note you have to convert to `int` when calculating the remainder since remainder operators do not work on `double`s.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 152799920;
    int p1 = n / 1E6; // Extract digits 6 and higher
    int p2 = (n % (int) 1E6)/ 1E3; // Extract 3 to 5
    int p3 = (n % (int) 1E3)/ 1E0; // Extract 0 to 2
    printf("%d/%d/%d", p1, p2, p3);

    return 0;
}
```

You can directly copy both of my answers as the main methods all compile. Your result should be `152/799/920` as expected.

Comment: I heavily advise against using double literals. Introducing unnecessary floating point conversions to integer calculations will cause trouble at some point. It may not be problem with these exact values and types in your example, but better not to teach bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the numbers as numbers, or as strings?

If strings, use `snprintf` to get the digits, and then use `strncpy` to copy out runs of 3.

If numbers, use modulus division to get the remainder after dividing by 1000, then shift the number by using integer division by 1000 and repeat 3 times.